# Как правильно определять размер файла в C?

Tags: c

Я уже знаю, что пара fseek/ftell

```
fseek(pointer, 0L, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(pointer);
```

скажет размер файла. Но мне странно, что для того, чтобы определить размер файла, нужно двигать указатель. Есть ли более "правильный" метод?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это и есть правильный метод. Содержимое файла может быть разбросано по всему диску, потому посчитать его как-то иначе нельзя - только узнать, какая позиция в байтах от начала.

Comment: Вы не правы. Во-первых, я не был бы столь категоричен, что это ЕДИНСТВЕННЫЙ правильный способ. Во-вторых, разбросанность файла по диску не имеет никакого значения. Файловая система всегда знает, какой точный размер файла и всегда предоставляет API, позволяющее этот размер выяснить.

Comment: Отчасти согласен, но я имел ввиду как раз платформонезависимый вариант, без использования различных API, только чистый C :)

Answer (score 2):

Можно юзать API. Если под Windows, то есть функция [GetFileSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364955(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Операционная система может предоставлять возможность узнать размер файла. Однако, такой код будет непереносим. К тому же, передвижение указателя - самый надёжный способ. По крайней мере, для файлов меньше 4G. Для бОльших файлов надо использовать другие функции и определить кое какие макросы (на вскидку не помню.. что-то вроде FILE_OFFSET_64).

Я с вами согласен, что открывать файл и двигать указатель только для того, чтобы узнать его размер - это полный дурдом. Но, к сожалению, другого переносимого способа нет.

Answer (score 1):

В Unix-like системах - через семейство системных вызовов stat, заполняющих struct stat. Там одно из полей (st_size) - размер файла. Кроме того, предоставляется куча другой информации о файле.